# I can not click anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I try to open and show my data in new browser page.

I open new page and show data. However I can not click, choose, or select anything.

My Javascript Code Below:

```
function CustomerId() {
  var veri = {
    Id: Id.GetValue(),
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/PanelGoster",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(veri),
    success: function (mydata) {
      if (mydata.error6 == true) {

      } else { // Success
        var something = window.open(url, '_blank');  // It opens in blank page but i can not click nothing.
        something.focus(); 


        ("#MusterilerGetir").html(mydata);          // Problem Here
      }
    },
    error: function () { }
  });
  return false;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hum... can you please explain what you need to do? cuz displaying a plain json in a new tab/page won't have any functionality, so its kinda obvious you wont need to click on anything

Comment: I want to display ("#MusterilerGetir").html(mydata);  in new tab page.

Comment: Yes, and you already displayed it in your previous question, right?

Comment: I guess the question is, how do you want to display it, plain text or with some functionalities

Comment: and what kind of functionalities you need, you need to explain it a bit more to get people help you

Comment: i have textboxes , buttons, comboboxes in my data.If i open them in new tab , i see them as text that is why i can not click to them.I need to click , write in textbox,buttons,combobox.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40043/discussion-between-abu-romaissae-and-user2902180)

Answer (score 0):

To summarize our discussion in the `chat` you can do the following to achieve what you need:

1. create a view with the html form you need to display
2. when a customer is selected open a new tab with an url to the previously created view and append a GET param of the customer id
3. in your controller, get the ID and load the required data to initialize the view, then show it.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

On the row marked with "Problem here" you are missing the jQuery identifier at the start. Add a `$` before `("#MusterilerGetir")` and you should be fine.

```
$("#MusterilerGetir").html(mydata);          // Problem Here
```